# How to deploy private repository as packages

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, github-enterprise, private-repository

I am using Enterprise Git 3.0, created a private repository.
I created a GitHub Personal Access Token, stored it in the repository's secret and referred it from the workflow. The PAT has rights to read/write packages.

I created the workflow action mentioned below, but whenever I run, it's giving **401: Unauthorized**.

Can someone guide me on what is missing.

```yaml
name: Git Deploy

on:
  push:

jobs:
  publish:
   
    strategy:
      matrix:
        maven: [  '3.6.3' ]
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
        server-id: github2 # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file
    
    - name: install maven   # If I don't do this, I was getting mvn not found error
      uses: stCarolas/setup-maven@v4.2
      with:
        maven-version: 3.6.3
       
    - name: read secrets from settings    
      uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.5.0
      with:
       servers: |
        [{
          "id": "github2",
          "username": "my github user id (Not email)",
          "password": "${{ secrets.PAT }}"
        }]
        
     
    - name: Build and deploy
      run: mvn -B deploy 
      env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          GITHUB_USER: "my github user id (Not email)"
```

Link I am referring
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-java-packages-with-maven

Comment: We switched from Enterprise to Cloud version and issue is resolved. Seems like that was environment issue.